# How to add Date and Time in RFC3339 format in java?

Tags: java

I have a date in string and a time in string ,now I just need to add them in RFC 3339 format and insert it into event object which is not taking string.
u can see my code below

```
    String date_from=req.getParameter("date_from").toString();
    String date_end=req.getParameter("date_end").toString();
    String time_from=req.getParameter("time_from").toString();
    String time_to=req.getParameter("time_to").toString();

     // here i m converting date_from which is string into Date object
    java.sql.Date dateFrom=  java.sql.Date.valueOf(date_from);
    java.sql.Date dateTo=  java.sql.Date.valueOf(date_end);




    String dateTimeStart=date_from+"T"+time_from+"Z";
    String dateTimeTo=date_end+"T"+time_to+"Z";

       //now here i just need to convert (string)dateTimeStart into object so that i able to use into my event class

           Event event = new Event();
           event.setSummary(userName);

           DateTime start = new DateTime(dateFrom, TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
           DateTime end = new DateTime(dateTo, TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
```

Hi , i am trying to make more clearer what my doubt is :

```
   DateTime end = new DateTime(dateTo, TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
```

see the above line of code , in first argument i want the format as "YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" the date "yyyy-MM-dd" i have in variable "dateTo" it is not containing the time with it.so to get time in hour , inutes , and seconds i am taking time in the variable time_to

```
      String time_to=req.getParameter("time_to").toString();
```

I used the following piece of code to convert into date object and used above in first line

```
     java.sql.Date dateTo=  java.sql.Date.valueOf(date_end);
```

same i did with time , but when i try to concate both date and time it give me a error when i use it as first argument in the following line of code

```
    DateTime end = new DateTime(dateTo, TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
```

Comment: RFC 3339 is a profile of [ISO 8601](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFC_3339). Search StackOverflow for "ISO 8601" to find hundreds of questions and answers.

Comment: The Joda-Time library offers an `Interval` class to represent a span of time. You may find it useful here.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you want to use RFC 3339 to pass to an object that does not take a string. But RFC 3339 *is* a string format.

Answer (score 0):

Use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")` to parse/format the dates. Check [SimpleDateFormat JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone) for details.

Comment: it is showing an error "Cannot format given Object as a Date"

Comment: What is the type and value of object you are trying to parse?

Comment: actually i have a date and time in a string variable,after concatenate(yyy-dd-mm t hh:mm:ss Z) have to convert it into object.

Answer (score 0):

Using java.time, with a very strict interpretation of RFC3339 with-time profile it looks as follows:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoField.*;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .appendValue(YEAR, 4)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
    .appendLiteral('T')
    .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendFraction(MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
    .optionalEnd()
    .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "Z")
    .toFormatter()
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)
    .withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE);

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-09-24T12:00:00.001+02:00", formatter);
String str = zdt.format(formatter);
```